# Getting 'expected an identifier' error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Im creating to create a food ordering app and on the food display page in the MaterialButton widget im getting an error 'expected an identifier' and 'Positional arguments must occur before named arguments. Try moving all of the positional arguments before the named arguments.'

```
                      Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: _con.favorite?.id != null
                                  ? OutlineButton (
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        _con.removeFromFavorite(_con.favorite);
                                      },
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                      shape: StadiumBorder(),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: 
                                  Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.favorite,
                                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                      ))
                                      : MaterialButton(
                                          elevation: 0,
                                          focusElevation: 0,
                                          highlightElevation: 0,
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            if (currentUser.value.apiToken == null) {
                                                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/Login");
                                            } else {
                                          _con.addToFavorite(_con.food);
                                        }
                                        },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               .l;,/
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
                                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                      shape: StadiumBorder(),
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.favorite,
                                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                      )),
                            ),
                                ] )
```

Comment: I removed all the imports and surrounding code because it was above character limit

Comment: Based on the error you have stated above, you have your named arguments before the position arguments.

Comment: Please indicate the actual line the error's from

Comment: One of the lower lines has `.l;,/`  hundreds of spaces to the right.  Is this intentional?

Comment: not intentional

Comment: error is on line before padding:EdgeInsets

Comment: it was the line with .l;,/ thank you

Comment: @pythonDON The code you have above does not have any issue. I will suggest properly outlining your problem and pasting a proper code example of your issue